# Safari Quick Website Search | How to tell Safari the way my full-text search works?

Tags: web, search, browser, solr, safari

The Apple browser Safari has a feature called "Quick Website Search". If you write the name of a website that you have already visited in the address bar, you can search directly on the page with a space followed by a search word, e.g. "widipedia dog".

On my Typo3 website I use a Solr full-text search with auto-complete. Safari recognizes these and queries them when using the Quick Website Search. The call Safari uses looks like this:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?id=0&L=0&eID=tx_solr_suggest&format=OpenSearch&q=<search-term>
```

It's very smart, that Safari automatically detects the search-engine, but unfortunately it's wrong. The page ID is missing. It should look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?id=1234&L=0&eID=tx_solr_suggest&format=OpenSearch&q=<search-term>
```

Even if you confirm the search, the wrong page will be displayed:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?id=0&L=0&q=<search-term>
```

It should look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?id=1234&L=0&q=<search-term>
```

Or even better:

```
https://www.example.com/search/?q=<search-term>
```

Does anyone know how I can tell Safari what the search query should look like?

Please excuse my english.
Many thanks and best regards.

Comment: It uses the OpenSearch specification. If you look at your source code you should have the specification linked there under a `<link rel="search"`: https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch/blob/master/opensearch-1-1-draft-6.md#OpenSearch_description_document

Comment: @MatsLindh Oh yes, you are right! The Plugin created this tag. I didn't realize it. In the linked XML-file, the id was missing. Thank you very much. If you like you can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [the OpenSearch specification](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch/blob/master/opensearch-1-1-draft-6.md#OpenSearch_description_document).

If you look at your source code you should have the specification linked there under a `<link rel="search"` element.

This resource is missing the id you want to have present (I'm not sure how TYPO3 generates it).